# Is it possible to replay Jenkins pipelines jobs based on their console output?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

Getting java.lang.InterruptedException and other errors which kills builds randomly. I'm looking for a solution that can parse logs and then rebuild a job if a specified string appears.

Naginator doesn't work for pipeline jobs.

Groovy Postbuild appears to not have the rebuild functionality.

PostBuild Action just runs a script/bash locally

Answer (score 0):

I tried to create a scene but sometimes it will be harmful because the same job calling itself during the failure and incase a regular failure of this job could be entered into an infinite looping.

```
pipeline {
    agent any;
    stages {
        stage('build') {
            steps {
                 
                script {
                    int n = env.BUILD_NUMBER
                    if( n % 2 != 0) {
                        error "I am fail because ${env.BUILD_NUMBER} % 2 = ${n % 2}"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        success {
            echo "SUCCESS ${currentBuild.result}"
        }
        failure {
            echo "FAILURE ${currentBuild.result}"
            build job: 'currentbuild', wait: false
        }
    }
}
```